# How to force Python to report an error if a local variable is referenced out of its scope?

Tags: python, scope

```
list1 = ["AAA", "BBB"]
for item in list1:
    print(item)

print (item) # <--- out of scope, but Python doesn't report any error
```

For the code above, although `item` is out of its scope, Python will not report an error.

Is it possible to force Python to report an error?

Comment: item is not out of scope.

Comment: `for` loops don't create any scope, so there is no error to report here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules

Comment: @ThierryLathuille no error except for "unexpected token '<'", etc.

Comment: is it possible to make item only visible  inside the loop?

Comment: No, but what would you want that? What is the actual problem that you encounter?

Comment: The immediate solution that comes to mind is wrap in a function, but as Thierry said - why do you need that behavior?

Comment: I think this is an error prone issue, especially for the beginner of python. Someone ask me to debug the issue of their code, and I found this is due to the local variable scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable that's being used in a loop will eventually arrive at the ***index "-1"*** of an iterable object. So each time you use that **same variable** used in **a previous loop**, it will return **list1[-1]** which is indeed the last element in every iterable object in python

**Solution**: you can use `del` keyword to delete that variable

```
list1 = ["AAA", "BBB"]
for item in list1:
    print(item)
del item    #now item is not a defined variable in our program.
print (item) #<--- will throw an error because the variable "item" no longer exists
```

`NameError` will be raised

Answer (score -1):

Functions have limited scope. So keep `for` loop inside function

```
def f():
  for item in list1:
    print(item)
print(item)
```

It will throw an error but you need to call a function whenever it required.